# C++ - type traits question

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I wish to know if it's possible in C++ to somehow handle the following situations:

**Situation 1)** *(Easily handled)*

```
class BasicFacility { }

template <typename U1, typename U2> class Facility : public BasicFacility { }
```

Suppose now that we want to have some compilation-time assertion and we want to check if the arbitrary type `typename T` models the `Facility`. This is pretty simple:

```
(boost::is_base_of<BasicFacility, T>::type)
```

**Situation 2)** *(???)*

Now let's assume that in the same situation we just have our template class:

```
template <typename U1, typename U2> class Facility { }
```

Obviously we can't use the same solution from *situation one*, because we can't write `statement<Facility, T>` (`Facility` is a template itself).

So, is there a way *(maybe, dirty, involving ugly casts, alignment-specific, ANYTHING that might work)* to check if some `T` actually equals some `template type` without introducing specific empty (auxiliary) base classes (because sometimes you simply can't) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you want to make sure a certain template parameter is an instance of the `Facility` template. That's simple:

```
template< typename Policy >
struct some_template; // note: only declared

template< typename U1, typename U1 >
struct some_template< Facility<U1,U2> > {
  // implementation
};
```

Of course, you could also generalize/formalize that:

```
template< typename T >
struct AssertFacility {}; // note: empty

template< typename U1, typename U2 >
struct AssertFacility< Facility<U1,U2> > {
  typedef Facility<U1,U2> result_t;
};

template< typename Policy >
class some_class {
  typedef AssertFacility<Policy>::result_t just_an_assertion;
public: 
  // more stuff
};
```

Answer (score 8):

It's pretty straightforward to roll your own test:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_facility : public boost::false_type { };

template <typename U1, typename U2>
struct is_facility< Facility<U1, U2> > : public boost::true_type { };
```